# DNS cache-on-demand server in Win7

Tags: windows-7, dns, cache

I live in a country that enjoys manipulating DNS entries for fun and profit. For various reasons, I cannot surf with a VPN running 100% of the time. Because some sites are only blocked via DNS spoofing, it would be very handy if I could run a local DNS server **that I could update on command during active VPN sessions.**

Is this granularity possible on Win7? Most of the DNS server related posts on SU are regarding the more config-friendly Linux platforms...

Comment: Can you change the DNS server's to google's ?

Comment: @HackToHell, Yes but I can only reach those servers when the VPN is on. I'd like to be able to say "ok, VPN is up, DNS cache refresh yourself please" and then when the VPN is off still use the cache.

Answer (score 1):

That is what [Portable DNS Cache](http://www.verigio.com/products/portable-dns-cache) does. It records DNS name resolutions and then plays it back. You can save and load cache files and DNS filters. Ask somebody to record those entries and send you the cache file. I'm not sure if it works via VPN though.

[image]